# SSRS: 2008 run same procedure with diff params for multi month report

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I'm all about recycling-)
I have report that user want to run for selected number of month back (let say from 1 to 12).
If they selected 6 month back (Jul-13 thru Jan-2104, then I need to produce 6 pages with monthly report on each of them, and sp is the SAME for all reports just different time params.

How I can reuse my code??
For now I have 12 Tablix(s) with New Page=START, Hide condition set based on datediff(m,startDate,endDate) individually for each Tablix.

Then I need to run same sp with diff params, can I add some dynamics into it? or I better to have 12 sp(s)?

Thanks
Mario

Comment: Is the layout and format of each page the same? If so, I would set your SP to return one dataset for all months selected and group that data by month in a List report item. You can set page breaks between each month in your List item Group.

Comment: Yes, format is 100% the same, just ran for different month period. But I need each month data on new page, so I need new tablix to implement page break I think, or probably I can try to use filters for each tablix.?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a single dataset and a List Report Item with an embedded Tablix:

1. Set the List Grouping to Group/Sort first by: `=Year(Fields!YourDateField.Value)` and then by `=Month(Fields!YourDateField.Value)`.
2. Set the Page Breaks on the List Grouping to "Between each instance of a group".
3. Drag your Tablix inside the List Report Item.

Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Ron !!!! Thanks for turning light in the tunnel. Trying it right now!!! Best.M  P.S. I also need header on each page with <month> value, hope to solve it too

Comment: You are quite welcome sir! You can use the following expression for the Month on your heading: `=format(Fields!YourDateField.Value,"MMMM")`